# Найти в тексте строки в Notepad+

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Прошу подскажите.
Как в Notepad+ с помощью Регулярных выражений сделать поиск ?
Есть строки в текстовом файле:
"title": "разный текст"
Найти всё в этом файле.

2. Есть строки в текстовом файле:
   "url": "разный текст"
   Найти всё в этом файле.
3. Есть всё в общей строке в текстовом файле:
   "title": "разный текст", "url": "разный текст"

Answer (score 0):

Искомое регулярное выражение:

`"title": "[a-zA-zа-яА-Я]*"`

Я все это сделал за 5 минут на regex101.com

Comment: для поиска url замените title на url